# merging lines based on pattern

Tags: regex, awk, sed

Could you suggest a sed/awk command to merge lines in a file that start with a pattern and ends with a brackets; the matching is of variable line numbers and governed with closing bracket.

eg For the following input, the extraction pattern has pattern1 as the begining and ends with '}'

```
blah blah
pattern1 {
blah blah 1
blah blah 2
blah blah 3
}
pattern1 {
blah blah 1
blah blah 2
}
```

the expected output is

```
blah blah 
partern1 {blah blah 1 blah blah 2 blah blah 3}
partern1 {blah blah 1 blah blah 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solves your question in awk, by registering whether we are in the middle of a pattern, and acting upon it. Given that your input file is named input.txt:

```
awk '/{/ {
    inPattern=1
}
{
    if (inPattern) {
        # When in a pattern, print the line (because of printf, this is without the newline).
        printf "%s ",$0;
    } else {
        # Otherwise, just print the line.
        print;
    }
}
/}/ {
    inPattern=0

    # Do this to go to a new line.
    print ""
}' input.txt
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed:

```
$ sed '/pattern1/ {:x; N; s/\n/ /; /}/! bx}' infile
blah blah
pattern1 { blah blah 1 blah blah 2 blah blah 3 }
pattern1 { blah blah 1 blah blah 2 }
```

Explanation:

```
/pattern1/ {    # Line matches pattern1
    :x          # Label to branch to
    N           # Add next line to pattern space
    s/\n/ /     # Replace newline with space
    /}/! bx     # If pattern space doesn't contain '}', branch to :x
}               # End of cycle: print pattern space
```

If you want to replace `pattern1` by a variable, you have to quote differently:

```
$ var=pattern1
$ sed "/$var/ {:x; N; s/\n/ /; /}/! bx}" infile
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me using in OSX or FreeBSD. Are you perhaps using GNU sed?  If so, it would be great to specify that in your answer, so that readers know that your answer is not portable.

Comment: @ghoti Yes, I'm using GNU sed. Let me check if I can make it portable.

Comment: @ghoti This being said, it works for me using the `--posix` flag. What doesn't work for you?

Comment: `sed: 1: "/pattern1/ {:x; N; s/\n ...": unexpected EOF (pending }'s)` is the error I see in FreeBSD and OSX. At first I thought problem was likely your use of `\n`, which is also not portable, but when I tried running `sed -e $'/pattern1/ {; :x; N; s/\\\n/ /; /}/! bx;}' file`, (with additional line separators), I got the error, `sed: 2: "/pattern1/ {; :x; N; s/ ...": invalid command code ;`. There's more here than I have time to debug at the moment, so .. good luck with it. :)

Comment: @ghoti Maybe the unescaped `}`. Not sure I can properly debug this without access to FreeBSD/OSX sed. I'll read up on portable sed, though :) Oh, and `\n` is not portable? Are FreeBDS/OSX sed not POSIX conformant? The [spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/utilities/sed.html) says that `\n` is supported.

Comment: Ah, my mistake, `\n` does indeed work inside the pattern space for a substitution. It just doesn't work in address space or the replacement string. Sorry for the confusion. The `$'...\\\n...'` notation is what is often used when you want to convert characters *to* newlines, rather than *from*.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sed solution that is portable (works in GNU sed, OSX, FreeBSD, etc.), though it it works on all patterns, not just the sections matching `/pattern1/`.:

```
sed -ne '/{/{;x;/}/d;p;x;h;d;}; /}/! {;H;d;}; /}/{;H;x;s/\n/ /g;};p' file
```

Broken out for easier reading, the script goes something like this:

- `/{/{;` - for any line containing an opening bracket (`{`)...

  - `x;/}/d;p;x;h;d;};` - print it .. unless it's a closing brace, and add it to our hold.
- `/}/! {;H;d;};` - for any line that without a closing brace, append it to our hold.
- `/}/{;H;x;s/\n/ /g;};` - For any line WITH a closing brace, append it, swap hold and pattern spaces, and substitute newlines for spaces.
- `p` - and print the result (since we had a `-n` as a sed option).

Works on your test input data, I haven't tested it on variations.

Note that this will certainly fail if there are embedded patterns within patterns. To handle that sort of scenario, you'd need to use an actual *language*, like [awk](/questions/tagged/awk), which can keep track of nesting level as it traverses your file.